# Woocommerce product variation not showing prices with my theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added an item with price variation, however the price and add to cart button are not showing on my theme. I've tested this on the default theme and it works fine, however with the them I'm using intially I found the line

```
<div class="single_variation_wrap" style="display:none;">
```

I changed the display, and the add to cart and quantity boxes shows. However The prices do not appear. With the default theme, there's a span of price and stock in the code, however with this theme nothing is in the code. The theme works with simple products.

I haven't found any one with an issue this specific any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

After earning my tumbleweed badge on this post I figured out the answer a month later.
The theme I was using was an older theme with an outdated version of jQuery. Woocoremece, Jigo shop and other plugins use the latest version and often come with it. So basically had 2 versions of JQuery on the site, so hence the conflict. Simply delete the older version and you should be good.

Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I had some jQuery in the new home page and I used this link in the Google API's

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in order to connect with jQuery. This line of script was in the footer of my theme (Woo Commerce My Style) and it affected the prices showing in the products pages, i.e. when I chose a price in the product page from the variations the price did not show up with the quantity button and add to cart button.

I then removed the above line of script and moved it to the header (you can see it here [Kitchens4u.ie](http://www.kitchens4u.ie)) page before the closing head tag. This seemed to sort out the issue.

I also seen somewhere else that jQuery comes as part of Wordpress. Is this True? And if it does then do we not need to use the above line of code to connect to jQuery through the Google API's.